# How to reduce the buffering size of video while using jw player?

Tags: video, jwplayer, buffering

I am using JW Player to show my videos in it. It is bufering for 10% of the video and then it starts. How can i reduce the buffering percentage of the video.

I'm Using some thing like

```
jwplayer('divID').setup({
    height: 500,
    width: 870,
    file: 'FileURl',
    logo: {
        hide: false
      }
});
```

So can any one let me know how can i reduce the buffering time.

Comment: Are you using RTMP? We only provide a bufferlength attribute for RTMP streaming.